# Flow - array of subtypes

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Having two objects, where B extends A, I can assign single instance of B to variable of type A. However, with arrays, that is not possible. Is there anything I can do to make this work? Thanks!

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { foo: string };
type ObjectB = ObjectA & {bar: number };

let objectBArray: ObjectB[] = [{ foo: 'test', bar: 42 }];
let objectAArray: ObjectA[] = objectBArray; // Does not work!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
let objectAArray: Array<$Subtype<ObjectA>> = objectBArray;
```

Not descriped in the docs, but seems to be official part of the API https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-subtype

Comment: The $Subtype utility has been deprecated. This answer really just results in an 'any' type which is to say that type safety has been lost.